# PHP if else statement testing whether api php field is empty

Tags: php, if-statement, ip-geolocation

I am attempting to get the `city` attribute out of an ip geolocation api. 
Sample of what is returned from the api:

`{"as":"AS38484 Virgin Broadband VISP","city":"Adelaide","country":"Australia","countryCode":"AU","isp":"iseek Communications","lat":-27,"lon":133,"org":"iseek Communications","query":"1.178.0.144","region":"","regionName":"","status":"success","timezone":"","zip":""}`

My code:

```
$query = '{"as":"AS38484 Virgin Broadband VISP","city":"Adelaide","country":"Australia","countryCode":"AU","isp":"iseek Communications","lat":-27,"lon":133,"org":"iseek Communications","query":"1.178.0.144","region":"","regionName":"","status":"success","timezone":"","zip":""}';
$query = @unserialize($query);
if($query && $query['status'] == 'success') {
    if(!empty($query['city'])) {
        $city =  $query['city'];
        // routine that uses $city gets called
    } else {
        $lat = $query['lat'];
        $lon = $query['lon'];
        // routine that uses $lat, $lon gets called
    }
}
```

Basically, the `if(!empty($query['city']))` is not behaving as expected (not that I would really know, I have been using PHP for that last week). I have also attempted setting `$city` before the if statement and then testing `if($city != '')`.

Question: No combination of condition finds and then sets the city attribute to `city`? And when there is not a city attribute it also skips the else part and doesn't set the `lat`/`lon`.

Note: the reason for the differentiation between `city` and `lat`/`lon` is the weather api I am querying prefers `city` but not every ip is able to provide one.

Thanks

Comment: Also what's the question?

Comment: Semicolon is there in the code :).
City attribute is never found is the problem sorry will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1)
You need to be using `json_decode` to unserialize the json data

2)
Since it will deserialize to an object you will access the fields with

```
 $query->city;
```

not

```
 $query['city'];
```

Answer (score 2):

$query is not a serialized PHP array, you'd see it if you didn't use '@' before `unserialize` call. it looks like JSON, so maybe `json_decode` is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

As @kao3991 and @andrew says, your data is JSON and not a serialized array. Try this:

```
$query = '{"as":"AS38484 Virgin Broadband VISP","city":"Adelaide","country":"Australia","countryCode":"AU","isp":"iseek Communications","lat":-27,"lon":133,"org":"iseek Communications","query":"1.178.0.144","region":"","regionName":"","status":"success","timezone":"","zip":""}';
$query = json_decode($query, true);
if($query && $query['status'] == 'success') {
    if(!empty($query['city'])) {
        $city =  $query['city'];
        // routine that uses $city gets called
    } else {
        $lat = $query['lat'];
        $lon = $query['lon'];
        // routine that uses $lat, $lon gets called
    }
}
```